# Pipenv won't lock after package install with python 3.8 due to python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, pipenv, python-3.8

I have python 3.6 and 3.8 on my machine.  I initialize a pipenv with:

```
pipenv --python 3.8
```

I do this otherwise by default it initializes with 3.6

This works well.  However, whenever I try to install a package (my use case was with aiohttp) I get the following error:

```
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.UnsupportedPythonVersion: dataclasses requires Python '>=3.6, <3.7' but the running Python is 3.8.0
```

I get this with:

```
pipenv install aiohttp
```

I then tried with a different package (tldextract) and got the same error message.

I can't find other references for this issue online.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Python 3.8` is recent release python release and not every packages has support for it yet. Its clearly said in pip `dataclasses requires Python '>=3.6, <3.7' but the running Python is 3.8.0`, which means the Python 3.8 is not supported by these libraries yet.

If you see the pip page for [aiohttp](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/), Python3.8 is not yet supported. So please check for supported pip-packages before installing them.